# how to compile jni using maven

Tags: java, c++, maven, java-native-interface

I have a simple Java class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public native void doSomthing();
}
```

Also I have a corresponding C++ file with the implementation of `doSomthing()` method.

My problem is that I need a `pom.xml` file, that will:

- Compile the Java class
- Compile C++ as dll
- Copy dll to `main/src/resources`
- Pack all as jar
- Deploy jar to repository

Could you please help me to write such a simple pom, without dividing these two files into tree  projects.

Thank you for your assistance.

PS: The produced jar will be platform dependent, but it is ok for my purposes.

Comment: There is a plugin for that: http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/

Comment: And your DLL should really go to `target/..`

Comment: Gyro Gearless, thank you for answer. As far as I understood, with this plugin, i have to create three projects. One parent, one for java and one for c++. is it correct? If yes, it seems strange, that for two files I need tree projects.

Comment: No it should be fine to have all in a single project. Just take care that the different plugin goals are bound to the "right" phase, so the different stages of compiling (generating native headers, compiling Java, compiling C, linking) are made in the correct order (defaults are perhaps fine)

Comment: w/o <packaging>so</packaging> it tried to link as g++ -shared -o target/myjar.jar

Comment: Thanks @BorisT - I've been trying to fix that for 3 days now.